# Pinescript - I need a simple code to not take a trade for 1 bar after my last trade closed

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

I need a little bit of help with some code, my system opens a trade on the same day it gets stopped out on when the entry conditions are still met. I trade on the daily time frame and would like my system to act as follows

Open Trade if conditions met (which it does)
If Target reached or Stop hit, close trade (which it does)

Pause for 1 bar after my last trade closed out (I don't even know where to start to code this)

If conditions are met enter trade (which it does)

Currently it does everything except the pause. I'm not sure how to do that?

I have tried googling other peoples code for this and It doesn't seem to be a very common question.
Where I have found similar questions with answers I have tried adding the code to my code without any luck

I am a complete beginner with code

Answer (score 0):

you can check your last trade by using `strategy.position`

```
trade_suppression_bars = 1
if (ta.barssince(strategy.position == 0) + 1) > trade_suppression_bars
    // enter previous strategy entry
    strategy.entry( ...
```

Comment: Can you see why it wont work? also in properties set recalculate to on bar close

longExitCondition = ta.sma(close, 50) < ta.sma(close, 200) and ta.sma(close, 9) < ta.sma(close, 200)
trade_suppression_bars = 1
longCondition = (ta.sma(close, 50) > ta.sma(close, 200) and ta.sma(close, 9) > ta.sma(close, 50))

if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

if (ta.barssince(strategy.position_size == 0) + 1) > trade_suppression_bars
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

I cant fit in the long exit condition code
you can see what it is at the top longExitCondition